# Regex return all characters

Tags: c#, regex

I was using the (.) to match all characters but it return back too with too many matches. How do i make it so it only 1 match?

```
 private MatchCollection RegexMatchingV2(string data, string regex)
    {
        MatchCollection col = null;
        try
        {
            col = Regex.Matches(data, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("RegexMatching ERROR:" + ex.Message);
        }
        return col;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MatchCollection col= RegexMatchingV2("return all of this data in 1 match", "(.)");
       Response.Write(col.Count);//Too much matches
    }
```

Comment: What is your goal? Matching an entire string indiscriminately is a pointless operation.

Comment: just too lazy to write to many conditional statements

Comment: What conditional statements? How does getting the entire string back as a single `Match` within a `MatchCollection` help you?

Answer (score 7):

To make it a single match use `(.*)`

The single `.` matches a single character.  The additional `*` means "zero or more".

**Edit** In response to the comment about two matches (the first match contains the string, and the second is an empty match):  The [Matches documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) indicates that it gives empty matches special treatment.  There is a good example on that page to show the behavior.  But the end result is that after the match, it does not do forward movement, so it picks up an empty match.  To prevent that, you could use beginning of line and end of line anchors:  `(^.*$)` or use the `+` to force at least one character to be included:  `(.+)`.

Comment: actually this returned 2 matches

Comment: @James007:  Good question - I made an attempt to answer it in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to match any number of any characters, change the `.` to `.*` to match zero or more, or `.+` to match one or more.